# Android call method but don't work on wifi but work on gprs

Tags: android, web-services, xamarin.android, wifi, gprs

we work with xamarin android and visual studio 2015.
we have an app who works since several months fine :)

This app when it starts call a webservice for to retrieve some data in json format.

All work fine, but last week we have a problem and we are COMPLETY lost about it !
Since last week, for one device when it call the web service we receive this error in the catch exception :

```
unable to read data from the transport connection Connection reset by peer  ...
```

Here is it the method on the device who call the WS:

```
 public override HttpResult ExecuteGet(Uri target)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 25600000;

    try
    {
        var response = client.GetAsync(target).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            return new HttpResult(content, null, null);
        }

        return new HttpResult(null, " ERROR MESSAGE ", response.StatusCode.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return new HttpResult(null, " ERROR MESSAGE", e.Message);
    }
}
```

well, now with the same device if we stop the wifi and call the webservice in GPRS that work.

Also we have two wifi, we also have noticed if the device connect on the second wifi and try to call the web service => that's work !

After talk with some colleague, they tell me to look to update my android version of the device , or wifi app on the device but for me the first thing we need to do will be to compare wifi 1 and wifi 2.

My question is, how i can compare two wifi ?
All suggestion are welcome because we search and we find nothing ...

Thanks for all guys that's really great to share your knowledge ...

Comment: This looks to be a hardware related problem, I don't think it's appropriate for stackoverflow as it may not be related to the xamarin project. That said, if you're positive that you've ruled out a hardware problem then it would be prudent to show us the snippet of code that is throwing the exception.

Comment: Thank you for adding the code. Has your place or work recently changed their firewall settings, as the code seems fine to me. The exception you get usually relates to a service that cannot be contacted, and as such it's likely the connection is getting blocked on your wifi network.

Comment: Hello digitalsa1nt, thanks for your reply. Yes for me the call to the WS works fine. And i've forget to tell you that we have 20 devices here. 19 works wells just one fail in wifi ...actually we have stop the wifi connection but we'd like to understand the problem ...  You know i'm null in network my question is perhpas stupid but do you think that there is a firewall for wifi 1 and a second firewall for wifi 2 ? Ok i will try to get more information about the call block by wifi network ... but hard to find something in world wide web ... thanks in advance if you have a plan :) have a nice day